# Conservation of momentum when one body is fixed

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

When we fire a gun, it recoils. Both bullet and gun gain in momentum. Before the shot, momentum of both is zero. 
  If we make the gun unmovable somehow, after the shot, what will be the effect on the bullet? After the shot, the gun has zero momentum, and so should the bullet as the law of conservation of momentum says. But the bullet will have velocity. Doesn't this negate the law of conservation of momentum?

Comment: Momentum is conserved when there is no net force acting on system. When you make the gun unmovable, you exert a force.

Comment: You have used a lot of incomplete sentences. Please edit your question

Comment: "After fire, the gun has momentum zero" - because you transferred the momentum to something else that now has nonzero momentum.

Comment: How do you plan to make the gun unmovable?

Comment: This is not a physics question because it relies on a fictional property - "unmovable". The question is meaningless.

Comment: @JBentley I agree. All questions relating to immovable objects, frictionless surfaces, or classical point particles should be closed as "not physics".

Answer (score 26):

When you say *we make the gun unmovable* what this really means is that you are fixing the gun to the Earth. So now when you fire the gun the momentum of the bullet must be equal and opposite to the momentum of the gun + the Earth.

So when you fire the gun you change the velocity of the Earth very slightly. However the Earth is so much more massive than the bullet that any change in the velocity of the Earth is far too small to measure.

Comment: I'd add to this, that fixing the gun to the Earth _does not_ change the (muzzle) velocity achieved by the bullet.  OP may be imagining that by reducing the recoil the performance of the gun would be improved.

Comment: @zwol: Actually, it does. The powder charge imparts an (approximately) fixed amount of kinetic energy to the bullet plus the gun, but the way it's distributed between the two depends on their relative masses. Specifically, the ratio between the kinetic energies of the bullet and the gun will be the inverse of the ratio of their masses: $E_{\rm bullet} / E_{\rm gun} = m_{\rm gun} / m_{\rm bullet}$. Thus, adding mass to the gun (by rigidly anchoring it to a massive object like the Earth) does increase the kinetic energy (and thus, necessarily, the velocity) of the bullet somewhat.

Comment: ... Of course, since the gun is *already* quite a bit more massive than the bullet it fires (at least, that's *usually* the case), most of the energy is already going into the bullet, and so adding more effective mass to the gun by anchoring it doesn't really make much difference. But "not much" isn't the same as "none at all".

Comment: @IlmariKaronen darn it, I knew I shoulda actually worked out the math before running my mouth.

Answer (score 8):

The point is that you cannot "make the gun unmovable".

Total initial momentum is $0$, so, by conservation of momentum, we will have:

$$m_{(gun)} v_{(gun)} + m_{(bullet)} v_{(bullet)} = 0$$

So that

$$v_{(gun)} = - \frac{m_{(bullet)}}{m_{(gun)}} v_{(bullet)}$$

If you want $v_{(gun)}$ to be *exactly* $0$ (with $v_{(bullet)}\neq 0$, of course) you have to make $m_{(bullet)}/m_{(gun)} = 0$, so you will need a gun with infinite mass!